# Terminal showing "Index error: List index out of range" and No such file or directory

Tags: python, indexing, libraries, cs50

[enter image description here][1]```
import sys

print("Hello my name is ", sys.argv[1])

```
[error message][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxacN.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEu37.png
```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in question's title

Comment: you should run code in `if len(sys.argv) > 1:`

Answer (score 1):

Is your file called `pratham.py`? If so, to run it on terminal you have to type `python pratham.py` to run the file. Furthermore, since you want a command line argument, you have to give it immediately after calling the program. For instance, running this:

```
python pratham.py Pratham
```

will yield this result:

```
Hello, my name is Pratham
```

Your `index out of range` problem is probably due to the fact that VSCode is running it automatically and not providing any command line arguments. In my `temp.py` file, VSCode is running the following:

```
/bin/python3.10 /home/***/Documents/temp.py
```

The first part is equivalent to `python` and the second to `temp.py`. As you see, no command line argument is provided.

Comment: I tried your solution but now its showing no such file or directory

Comment: @Prathamsolanki Could you please share your file tree and the instruction you typed?

Comment: By the way, CS50 is a great course!